# Does a Fully Qualified Domain Name need a period?

Tags: linux, dns, domain-name, fqdn

I'm confused about FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name). Is it necessary to end FQDN with a period? Like `sun` or `sun.tuc.noao.edu.` or `sun.tuc.noao.edu`.  What's the difference?

Comment: I've encountered more than one email address validator (on websites) that rejected an email address with a dot on the end. And the dot should be 'required' by all browsers, in the sense that if you don't put it, the browser is supposed to interpret the domain name as partial - within one or more local domains - before (if that fails) interpreting it as an absolute domain name. Do modern browsers actually do that? I'd like to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**How IT Works: Domain Name
>   System**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.01.howitworksdns.aspx)
>
> All DNS records actually end with the period character (.) which
>   represents the root of the DNS hierarchy, but it's rarely printed and
>   is usually just assumed. A domain name that includes the trailing
>   period character is said to be a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN).
>   However, domain names where the period character is implicit are also
>   commonly referred to as FQDNs.
>
> <sup>*Source: [TechNet Magazine](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.01.howitworksdns.aspx)*</sup>

See also:

- [Trailing Dots in Domain Names](http://www.dns-sd.org/trailingdotsindomainnames.html)
- [No, that dot in the domain name of the URL is not a mistake.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/web-fully-qualified-domain-name.html)

Answer (score 3):

Usually you don't the (dot) . at the end of a FQDN except if it is in a DNS.
If you are adding this FQDN for an internal machine/server at most of cases we don't add the (dot) at the end.

take a look at [2] DNS specification, RFC 1034, way back in 1987:

> When a user needs to type a domain name, the length of each label is
>   omitted and the labels are separated by dots (".").  Since a complete
>   domain name ends with the root label, this leads to a printed form
>   which ends in a dot.  We use this property to distinguish between:
>
> - a character string which represents a complete domain name
>      (often called "absolute").  For example, "poneria.ISI.EDU."
> - a character string that represents the starting labels of a
>      domain name which is incomplete, and should be completed by
>      local software using knowledge of the local domain (often
>      called "relative").  For example, "poneria" used in the
>      ISI.EDU domain.

**References:**

[1] http://www.dns-sd.org/trailingdotsindomainnames.html

[2] http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt