# Redirection domain with https and a dot at the end of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I get a domain redirect, e.g. https://google.com. (with dot) to https://google.com/

Redirection works with htaccess but only for http:// queries

How can I get this redirect? Maybe I need to add some DNS record? Or maybe there is a separate htaccess rule for https://?
I currently have the following rule for http:// and it works:

```
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} \. $
RewriteRule (. *) Https://google.com/$1 [R = 301, L]
```

Is there anyone here who can solve the problem?
Please help

Comment: What is the use case for a url "with a dot at the end", like `www.mysite.com.`???

Comment: `google.com.` is _not_ a valid host name or domain name. You will never receive a request to such host. Could it be that you actually want to redirect requests to a host name that _starts with_ `google.com.` but actually points to another domain? Something like `google.com.evilsite.com`? So that you are trying to trick people?

Comment: A fully qualified domain has to have a dot in the end. Check out this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646446/does-a-fully-qualified-domain-name-need-a-period